# SQL Matlab (ambiguous)

Tags: sql, matlab, postgresql

First, I want to say I'm a **COMPLETE** newbie in SQL, so please bear with me, myself and my stupidity.

I've been trying to get data through Matlab by using

```
​sqlquery='SELECT patientid, visit_results.visitid, segmentid, init_time, end_time, num_steps, "distance_F", height, weight, birth FROM visit, visit_results, patient WHERE visit_results.visitid=visit.visitid AND visit_results.visitid=patient.patientid';
```

Now, I know for sure that the three tables exist. Both `visit_results` and `visit`  have `visitid` as Primary Key.

I want to get data from a third table, `patient`, whose primary key is `patientid`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does visit_results have a patientid column? What about visit?

Comment: @RobertoNavarro No, it doesn't

Comment: @RobertoNavarro But `visit` does :)

Comment: See my response below -- :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining visitid to patientid, which is not the right join (deduction based on column names).. try this instead:

```
sqlquery='
SELECT patient.patientid,
       visit_results.visitid,
       segmentid,
       init_time,
       end_time,
       num_steps,
       "distance_F",
       height,
       weight,
       birth
  FROM visit, visit_results, patient
 WHERE visit_results.visitid = visit.visitid AND visit.patientid = patient.patientid'
```

Comment: I tried as soon as I got your comment, but unfortunately is not working.  I still have the same `Column reference "patientid" is ambiguous`

Comment: I think I got it... is because the first `patientid`, I have to specify the table, right?